# Unable to generate thumbnail image for certain products

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

We are using Magento 2.1.8 and have an issue with image generation. All items in our catalog have the image options set for base, small, etc. For certain items in the catalog however, no thumbnail is generated and they appear blank in the list. This is visible in the Item "Ice Skating Competition Dress" on our homepage at https://www.ohfrock.com/

I have tried all I can find including completely removing and recreating the images/cache directory but I cannot get this and other products to display a thumbnail. Is there anywhere I can look at a data level that may be blocking this or some other way to debug what the issue might be

Answer (score 0):

Delete the product in catalog, update again. Catalog image should be updated in media/catalog folder inside the pub, where in your store, your retrieving from the theme image folder.

Comment: This has happened across several products so it is both systemic and not practical to just delete them. I am hoping to find what is blocking the image generation to put a permanent fix in place should this happen again. Thx